# Select2 dropdown overlapping text input after DOM is updated

Tags: javascript, html, jquery-select2

[image]I'm using older version of select2 (3.5), and i have a problem with dropdown position changing when i apply some element that modifies the app height in some way.

When height is modified in the background and dropdown is still open, the dropdown moves above the select2 text field, hiding it. How do i make dropdown position to always be below the select2 text, as it should be.

Comment: Attach screenshot of your issue. So understand your issue more in detail.

Comment: Screenshot added.

Comment: Give textbox to min height.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by triggering scroll down on window for 1px and than dropdown gets re-aligned with the text field. Might not be the nicest solution but it works for me.
Here's the code:

```
window.scrollBy(0, 1);
```